# I do not retrieve the correct value, with a List of Values ​which depends on Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)

Tags: apex, cascading, lov

with a List of Values ​​which depends on Cascading LOV Parent Item(s), when editing I do not retrieve the correct value. refreshing the list makes me lose my selected item

i have one item **P1_TYPE** which impacts the List Of Values **P1_CODE** with the PL/SQL

```
select
  display_value||' ('|| value_code ||')' as display_value,
  value_code 
    from data d
    inner join list l
        on l.list_id = d.list_id
    where list_name = :P1_TYPE
```

When i add a new Data, i don't have any problem but when i editing the popUp i think the list of values is refresed and i lost the values.

since the good value is also in DB, I wanted to recover it except that this may impact the fact that I am not in Edition.